# Is there dictionary of roots of words?

Tags: dictionaries

E.g.

- zeal -> zealot -> zealotry

I'm interesting in short dictionary, in this case it will contain only **zeal**.

Of cource, every english roots.

Comment: A dictionary will typically give a primary entry for the root word only, unless the disambiguation has changed the meaning to any significant degree.  Otherwise, it will show the disambiguation in the main entry. Besides, use an online dictionary. The search function will filter out your unwanted terms.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find a lot of material for free on the web on this topic ... Have a look at 
http://www.prefixsuffix.com/rootchart.php

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. Can you say, is this a complete list, say >90% of main roots?

Comment: For example, there is no `zeal`, can you tell me, why?

Comment: @user2496: That's because a relatively uncommon/dated word like ***zeal*** wouldn't be in the top 90% of "main roots" (probably not in the top 99%, or even 99.9%). It certainly doesn't appear in [5000 most common words in English](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/common-words-5000.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you're looking for an Etymological Dictionary, which shows how words developed, or where there meaning originated from.

Try this online version:
http://www.etymonline.com/

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=z&allowed_in_frame=0 See, there are repeats, zeal, zealot, etc...

Comment: For the start, I want to collect only roots, that is why I'm looking for short roots dictionary. Anyway, great tree of words, how the leafs appears with suffixies and prefixies from the roots will be too great.